# Validating a dynamic knockout observable ViewModel, same viewmodel has to be saved to DB

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a view model in below format:

```
var usersViewModel = function() {

 this.userdata = [
 { 
   UserNumber: "12", 
   UserName: "Jennifer",  
   Partitions: "01",
   Code: "2356", 
   Authority: "Standard User", 
   Keyfob: "Keyfob 03",
   ZwaveLock: false 
 },
 {
   UserNumber: "13",
   UserName: "Pinkman",
   Partitions: "03", 
   Code: "4234", 
   Authority: "Guest",
   Keyfob: "Keyfob 01",
   ZwaveLock: true 
 },
 {
   UserNumber: "14", 
   UserName: "Nolan", 
   Partitions: "02", 
   Code: "1233",   
   Authority: "Standard User",
   Keyfob: "Keyfob 02", 
   ZwaveLock: "false" 
 }];
};
ko.applyBindings(new usersViewModel());
```

How can I do a clientside validation on this?

I have these requirements:

- Usernumber must be between 1 to 100.
- User code should be 4 digit only.
- Username should allow characters only.

Comment: Look into the knockout-validation plugin; it's widely used, very stable and there are lots of questions and answers about it here..

Answer (score 0):

Using  [ko validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation), your requirements would be meet by the following validation observables:

```
var UserDataElement = function (dataObj) {
    dataObj.UserName = ko.observable(dataObj.UserName).extend({
        pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]*$'
    })

    dataObj.Code = ko.observable(dataObj.Code).extend({
        minLength: 4
    })

    dataObj.UserNumber = ko.observable(parseInt(dataObj.UserNumber)).extend({
        min: 1,
        max: 100
    })
    return dataObj;
}
```

To finish the setup and display any upfront errors: `ko.validation.group(vm.userdata).showAllMessages()`

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/2vF3f/) for full implementation. In regards to saving, `ko.toJSON(vm)` should suffice.

Comment: I need a viewmodel, so that below functionality should be achieved
as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/102/
On edit of the row the viewmodel should be updated with the edited value